# Kivy selectable button in RecycleView

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp


Builder.load_string(
    '''
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path


<CustomOneLineIconListItem>

    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon


<PreviousMDIcons>

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding: dp(20)

        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'magnify'

            MDTextField:
                id: search_field
                hint_text: 'Search icon'
                on_text: root.set_list_md_icons(self.text, True)

        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            viewclass: 'Button'
            key_size: 'height'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                default_size: None, dp(48)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
'''
)


class CustomOneLineIconListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()


class PreviousMDIcons(Screen):

    def set_list_md_icons(self, text="", search=False):
        '''Builds a list of icons for the screen MDIcons.'''

        def add_icon_item(name_icon):
            self.ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "CustomOneLineIconListItem",
                    "icon": name_icon,
                    "text": name_icon,
                    "callback": lambda x: x,
                }
            )

        self.ids.rv.data = []
        for name_icon in md_icons.keys():
            if search:
                if text in name_icon:
                    add_icon_item(name_icon)
            else:
                add_icon_item(name_icon)


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = PreviousMDIcons()

    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        self.screen.set_list_md_icons()


MainApp().run()
```

Provided this code, how can I know which button is pressed, to execute a function that depends on the button information. The code is just an example of the icons in kivy, for context, those buttons will have names, which will have to be used in functions. I need the search, since the list will be extremely long. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

[image: Screenshot of the interface]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exatcly are you looking for, but I guess you want to run a function whenever a specific button is pressed. For that you simlply need to bind a function to `on_release`

```
MDIconButton:
    icon: 'magnify'
    on_release: root.do_something()
```

If you do this, it will know wich button was pressed, and will execute the `do_something` function.

```
class PreviousMDIcons(Screen):
    def do_something(self):
        print("hi")
```

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the question, the IconButton you are refering to is the magnifier next to the search bar, not the individual items of the list.
What I want to do is if I click one of the items it will do a specific function